# What does "Assigned" mean in the Azure AD Application user list?

Tags: active-directory, azure, single-sign-on, entra-id

Within the Azure portal, inside an Active Tenant I have an application with users listed, of which are created in the tenant.

What does the term **Assigned** mean?

[image: Assigned]

I incorrectly assumed that it meant the user existed in the Azure tenant, but could not access the application.  However, this cannot be true because I can successfully log in as a user who is not assigned:

[image]

Can anyone offer an explanation please in the absence of a help file (nudge nudge Microsoft!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field is most likely being used to track licensing or plans from Microsoft / other SaaS solutions.  Do the other users you have who have 'Yes' next to their name use something like Azure AD Premium, Office 365 or access to one of the Apps in the Azure AD SSO-supported list?

Comment: I think you could be correct there.  I'm currently doing battle with MS Support as my domains are somehow locked into "another tenant" even though another tenant doesn't exist, so cannot test out the theory just yet.  I'll award the bounty anyway as this seems to be correct.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a user to a web application will make the web app appear on the myapps.microsoft.com page. The single place to access all your applications.

See this SO question for more details.

[Azure Active Directory Assigned Users Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28358298/1558220)